# How to check if laptop screen is turn on?

Tags: xubuntu, laptop, screen

In my new laptop in Xubuntu 16.04 toggle screen Fn button is not working so I need to write a script that will toggle the display, for this to work I need to check if screen is on or off, how can I do that from command line?

I can use:

```
sudo vbetool dpms off/on
```

but I need to know which command to execute, I didn't test it yet because will need to turn my display on after I turn in off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ended up with this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

file=/tmp/display

if [ -e $file ]; then
    rm $file
    sudo vbetool dpms on

else
    touch $file
    sudo vbetool dpms off
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

xrandr can list the on screens for you. You can then grep any or all of their id's from there:

```
xrandr --listmonitors
```

I wrote a bash screen toggle script using it and mentioned it in a similar question:
[Lubuntu: hotkey to toggle displays](https://askubuntu.com/questions/648922/lubuntu-hotkey-to-toggle-displays)

Comment: I'm using Fedora right now and when I've run xrandr when laptop lid is closed (it turn off the screen) I have the same output as when it's open (screen on). The output say connected and I also have error about size of gamma.